# How to you suricata to work in IPS mode in Ubuntu?

Tags: error-handling, vmware-player, intrusion-detection

i am trying to install suricata in vmware player and  when i try the

```
suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml
```

i get the error of

> - [ERRORCODE: SC_ERR_CONF_YAML_ERROR(240)] - Failed to parse configuration line 382: did not find expected key

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a problem with formatting of the YAML file. YAML uses spaces for indent and usually this problem appears when tabs have been used instead.